# The volume “boot” has only 0 byte disk space remaining

Tags: 10.04, boot, filesystem, updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Free up more space on /boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/free-up-more-space-on-boot)

I am in **Ubuntu 10.04**.

When I install the software updates with "**Update Manager**", there is a pop up dialog which tells me "*The volume "boot" has only 0 byte disk space remaining*"

My current kernal in use is:

```
myname:~$ uname -r
2.6.32-37-generic
```

The content of boot folder is:

```
myname:~$ ls -lah /boot
total 217M
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 3.0K 2012-01-13 15:18 .
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 4.0K 2012-01-13 15:21 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 626K 2010-04-16 16:01 abi-2.6.32-21-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 637K 2011-01-11 03:18 abi-2.6.32-28-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 637K 2011-02-11 21:56 abi-2.6.32-29-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 637K 2011-03-02 04:27 abi-2.6.32-30-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 637K 2011-04-09 02:35 abi-2.6.32-31-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 637K 2011-04-21 01:52 abi-2.6.32-32-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 637K 2011-07-30 03:17 abi-2.6.32-33-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 638K 2011-09-14 03:51 abi-2.6.32-34-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 638K 2011-10-11 23:33 abi-2.6.32-35-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 638K 2011-11-09 03:33 abi-2.6.32-36-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 638K 2011-12-03 04:08 abi-2.6.32-37-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 114K 2010-04-16 16:01 config-2.6.32-21-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 114K 2011-01-11 03:18 config-2.6.32-28-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 114K 2011-02-11 21:56 config-2.6.32-29-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 114K 2011-03-02 04:27 config-2.6.32-30-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 114K 2011-04-09 02:35 config-2.6.32-31-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 114K 2011-04-21 01:52 config-2.6.32-32-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 114K 2011-07-30 03:17 config-2.6.32-33-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 114K 2011-09-14 03:51 config-2.6.32-34-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 114K 2011-10-11 23:33 config-2.6.32-35-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 114K 2011-11-09 03:33 config-2.6.32-36-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 114K 2011-12-03 04:08 config-2.6.32-37-generic
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4.0K 2012-01-13 15:18 grub
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  14M 2010-08-24 12:00 initrd.img-2.6.32-21-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  14M 2011-01-27 16:26 initrd.img-2.6.32-28-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  14M 2011-03-25 11:11 initrd.img-2.6.32-29-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  14M 2011-03-28 09:32 initrd.img-2.6.32-30-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  14M 2011-06-20 15:33 initrd.img-2.6.32-31-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  14M 2011-06-22 13:02 initrd.img-2.6.32-32-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  14M 2011-08-10 10:37 initrd.img-2.6.32-33-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  14M 2011-10-21 19:02 initrd.img-2.6.32-34-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  14M 2011-11-11 10:03 initrd.img-2.6.32-35-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  14M 2011-12-05 17:13 initrd.img-2.6.32-36-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  14M 2012-01-13 15:18 initrd.img-2.6.32-37-generic
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  12K 2010-08-05 00:24 lost+found
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 157K 2010-03-23 11:37 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1.7M 2010-04-16 16:01 System.map-2.6.32-21-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1.7M 2011-01-11 03:18 System.map-2.6.32-28-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1.7M 2011-02-11 21:56 System.map-2.6.32-29-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1.7M 2011-03-02 04:27 System.map-2.6.32-30-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1.7M 2011-04-09 02:35 System.map-2.6.32-31-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1.7M 2011-04-21 01:52 System.map-2.6.32-32-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1.7M 2011-07-30 03:17 System.map-2.6.32-33-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1.7M 2011-09-14 03:51 System.map-2.6.32-34-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1.7M 2011-10-11 23:33 System.map-2.6.32-35-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1.7M 2011-11-09 03:33 System.map-2.6.32-36-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1.7M 2011-12-03 04:08 System.map-2.6.32-37-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1.2K 2010-04-16 16:03 vmcoreinfo-2.6.32-21-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1.2K 2011-01-11 03:20 vmcoreinfo-2.6.32-28-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1.2K 2011-02-11 21:57 vmcoreinfo-2.6.32-29-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1.2K 2011-03-02 04:29 vmcoreinfo-2.6.32-30-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1.2K 2011-04-09 02:38 vmcoreinfo-2.6.32-31-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1.2K 2011-04-21 01:54 vmcoreinfo-2.6.32-32-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1.2K 2011-07-30 03:19 vmcoreinfo-2.6.32-33-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1.2K 2011-09-14 03:53 vmcoreinfo-2.6.32-34-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1.2K 2011-10-11 23:34 vmcoreinfo-2.6.32-35-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1.2K 2011-11-09 03:34 vmcoreinfo-2.6.32-36-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1.2K 2011-12-03 04:10 vmcoreinfo-2.6.32-37-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 3.9M 2010-04-16 16:01 vmlinuz-2.6.32-21-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 3.9M 2011-01-11 03:18 vmlinuz-2.6.32-28-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 3.9M 2011-02-11 21:56 vmlinuz-2.6.32-29-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 3.9M 2011-03-02 04:27 vmlinuz-2.6.32-30-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 3.9M 2011-04-09 02:35 vmlinuz-2.6.32-31-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 3.9M 2011-04-21 01:52 vmlinuz-2.6.32-32-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 3.9M 2011-07-30 03:17 vmlinuz-2.6.32-33-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 3.9M 2011-09-14 03:51 vmlinuz-2.6.32-34-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 3.9M 2011-10-11 23:33 vmlinuz-2.6.32-35-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 3.9M 2011-11-09 03:33 vmlinuz-2.6.32-36-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 3.9M 2011-12-03 04:08 vmlinuz-2.6.32-37-generic
```

**Questions:**

1. Among those files in boot folder, which can be removed?
2. How to remove by using *Synaptic Package Manager* tool?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run `sudo apt-get remove linux-image-<version>` in a terminal for every kernel you don't need.

As an example `sudo apt-get remove linux-image-2.6.32-21-generic` will remove the 2.6.32-21-generic version of the kernel and all the associated files. This will free up space on the /boot partition.

To find out which one you should keep, run `uname -r`. In your specific case, the ones you can safely remove are versions:
`2.6.32-21-generic` and `2.6.32-28-generic` - `2.6.32-36-generic`

Comment: Thank you , I am also interested in how to remove by using Synaptic Package Manager tool, basically I don't know which one from left side options I should choose in the tool.

Comment: And I do not have files with name contain linux-image-<version>, of course I know <version> is dynamical thing. So, can you just point out with files names in my boot folder, which files can be deleted?

Comment: Edited my answer to include the versions you can remove.

Comment: `sudo apt-get autoremove` should clean all those out

Answer (score 2):

Open synaptic. Search for "linux-image". Select all versions that you dont use (probably 2.6.32-36-generic and below). Right click, mark for removal then hit apply.